# In WPF, how to put some ComboBox(es) and text inside the Contents of a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, I want to dynamically put some ComboBox(es) and text inside the Contents of a TextBlock as shown in the picture. How can I do this dynamically using code? I made this using following XAML in design window. Thank you all...

```
        <Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
            <Grid>
                 <TextBlock x:Name="tb" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20">
                      I want to put a ComboBox inside the contents of a TextBlock dynamically. As shown in this picture.
    <ComboBox >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="One" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="147"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Two" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="147"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Three" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="147"/>
    </ComboBox>
    How I can do this. I want to put a ComboBox inside the contents of a TextBlock dynamically. As shown in this picture.
    <ComboBox >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="One" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="147"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Two" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="147"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Three" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="147"/>
    </ComboBox>
     How I can do this.I want to put a ComboBox inside the contents of a TextBlock dynamically. As shown in this picture. How I can do this. I want to put a ComboBox inside the contents of a TextBlock dynamically. As shown in this picture. How I can do this. I want to put a ComboBox inside the contents of a TextBlock dynamically. 
    <ComboBox >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="One" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="147"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Two" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="147"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Three" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="147"/>
     </ComboBox>
     As shown in this picture. How I can do this. I want to put a ComboBox inside the contents of a TextBlock dynamically. As shown in this picture. How I can do this. I want to put a ComboBox inside the contents of a TextBlock dynamically. As shown in this picture. How I can do this. I want to put a ComboBox inside the contents of a TextBlock dynamically. As shown in this picture. How I can do this.

    </TextBlock>     
  </Grid>
 </Window>
```

[image]

Comment: give the ComboBox and name, you can add them in code behind. If you're using MVVM, then make the list your view model.

Comment: If you are looking for a dynamic/MVVM solution then you can explore DataTemplate and DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: Dear sir, Actually a want some/few lines of code behind ... as a hint... Anyways thank you ... Let me try...

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var textBlock = new TextBlock(){ TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap};
            var run1 = new Run { Text = "text text1 text1" };
            var run2 = new Run { Text = "text2 text2 text2" };
            var run3 = new Run { Text = "text3 text3 text3" };
            var combo1 = new ComboBox(){Items = { "item1", "item2" , "item3" }};
            var combo2 = new ComboBox(){Items = { "item1", "item2" , "item3" } };

            textBlock.Inlines.Add(run1);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(combo1);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(run2);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(combo2);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(run3);

            MyGrid.Children.Add(textBlock);
        }
```

And don't forget to name your Grid accordingly:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" />
</Window>
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Worked. Thank you so much dear sir...